# Chain rule confusion(multivariable functions)

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I am confused bz the chain rule of multivariable function. I know, that sometimes it is impossible to dot it.

For example i have the following functions:

$f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1x_2^2 + x_1^3x_2\\x_1^2x_2 + x_1 + x_2^3\\\end{bmatrix}$

$g(u) = \begin{bmatrix} e^u \\ u^2 + u\\\end{bmatrix}$

Is it possible to take a derivative of $f(g)$ or $g(f)$. If not - why?

And in general, when can we take a derivative of such functions(multivariable) and when not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ and $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$.

Both functions are of class $C^{\infty}$ on their domains, so we only need to know how composing the two functions makes sense. We can't compose $g$ with $f$, but we can compose $f$ with $g$ and $f \circ g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$: it is a vector function, and $(f\circ g)'(u) = J_f(g(u)) g'(u)$, where $J_f$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Can you explain in more details, why can't we compose g with f?

Comment: @DanielYefimov because $g \circ f$ makes sense only when the codomain of $f$ coincides with the domain of $g$. Here, the codomain of $f$ is $\Bbb R^2$ and the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb R$

Comment: Now i got it. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I helped. You're welcome.

Comment: May i ask you the same about the derivative of inverses of f and g?
I mean if it is possible to do?
My intuition tells me, that in case of f - the derivative of its inverse exists(in g - it doesn't). But i don't know why

Comment: As i unerstood derivative g's inverse doesn't exists, because the derivative  matrix doesn't exist(it's just a vector. In case of f - it is exist, because the determinant of derivative matrix is not equal zero.

Comment: @DanielYefimov I suppose that by the derivative matrix of $f$ you mean the Jacobian matrix. If the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $f$, at some point, is non-zero, then $f$ is locally invertible at that point. However, such a thing doesn't tell us whether or not $f$ is invertible (i.e. globally). If the inverse of $f$ is known to exist, and is differentiable, then its Jacobian matrix is the inverse of the Jacobian matrix of $f$. Anyway, for this particular $f$, I don't think that an inverse exists. For $g$, I have no clue.